# Will Clash of Clans overwrite my account, if my son has his own account on my old iPhone?

Tags: ios, clash-of-clans, game-center

I have given my old iPhone to my son who has his own GameCenter ID. It has been signed out by myself, and signed in with his account info. When he opens Clash of Clans, a pop up asks if he wants to load his village. He does, but it says: "Warning: progress in the current game will be lost." Then it asks you to choose Cancel or Load. He chooses Load. Another popup reading: "Are you absolutely sure that you want to delete the current village and replace it with: *my son's name*"

Does this mean that if he accepts, it will overwrite the village on my account with his?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes. if you want to keep your account you need to link your account to a game center account and then transfer your account to a different device.  Then he can overwrite your village without you losing it.

Answer (score 0):

You won't lose the village. U can freely switch back and forth by logging in with different game center id's. The villages are saved to the game enter ID, not the Clash app.